# How to test DatadogMeterRegistry in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have custom metrics which is pushed to the metrics endpoint, I use the metrics endpoint to push to Datadog. I wanted to know how to test `DatadogMeterRegistry` in spring boot application.

I found something in [GitHub](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/363b9d8e1d4af93a986eac6595b71493c2de5708/implementations/micrometer-registry-datadog/src/test/java/io/micrometer/datadog/DatadogMeterRegistryTest.java) but it was dead-end

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomMetricsConfig {

    @Bean
    public MeterBinder tlsServiceMetrics(TslService tslService) {
        return registry -> {
            registry.gauge("TestMetrics.summaryCount", testService, v -> v.getService().getSummary().size()).sum());
        };
    }
}
```